Joda-time type mapping in Hibernate ORM 6
I'm new to Java and I am trying to migrate from Hibernate 5 to 6. My application uses joda-time for the timestamp data type. It is using both annotation and hibernate mapping files.
Following is a class use annotation:
package com.mydomain.myapp.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;

@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "CARD_DATA")
public class CardData {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CARD_ID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Long userId;
    @Column(name = "CARD_NAME")
    private String cardName;
    @Column(name = "EFFECTIVE_DATE")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
    private LocalDate effectiveDate;
    @Column(name = "EXPIRATION_DATE")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
    private LocalDate expirationDate;
    @Column(name = "CREATED_TS")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    private LocalDateTime createdTs;
    @Column(name = "CREATE_USER_NAME")
    private String createUserName;
}

With the other entity, the application uses hibernate mapping file as follows:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mydomain.myapp.model.CardLendRate" table="CARD_LEND_RATE">
        <id name="CardLendRateId" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="CARD_LEND_RATE_ID" precision="38" scale="0" />
            <generator class="org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator">
                <param name="sequence_name">LEND_RATE_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="cardTypeCode" type="string">
            <column length="4" name="CARD_TYPE_CODE" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="userOwnerName" type="string">
            <column length="20" name="USER_OWNER_NAME" />
        </property>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="effectiveDate" type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate">
            <column length="7" name="EFFECTIVE_DATE" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="expirationDate" type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate">
            <column length="7" name="EXPIRATION_DATE" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="createdTs" type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime">
            <column name="CREATED_TS" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="createUserName" type="string">
            <column length="50" name="CREATE_USER_NAME" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="modifiedTs" type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime">
            <column name="MODIFIED_TS" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="modifyUserName" type="string">
            <column length="50" name="MODIFY_USER_NAME" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="notes" type="string">
            <column length="500" name="NOTES" not-null="false" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


DatasourceConfiguration:
package com.mydomain.myapp.config;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.transaction.SystemException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataSourceConfiguration.class);
    
    @Value("${dpre.schema.name}")
    public String appDbSchema;

    @Autowired
    private  Environment environment;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("sessionFactory") SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource datasource) throws IOException, SystemException {
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver pathMatchingResourcePatternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(datasource);
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.mydomain.myapp.model");
        sessionFactory.setMappingLocations(pathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources("classpath*:/com/mydomain/myapp/model/*.hbm.xml"));
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", appDbSchema);
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", environment.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", environment.getProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", environment.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation", "true");
        return hibernateProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

}


The problem is that the type attribute has been removed in Hibernate 6 (for the @Type annotation usage). I'm not sure if they removed it from using hibernate mapping or not?
This is the error I got:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cardLendRateService': Error creating bean with name 'cardLendRateService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cardLendRateDAO': Error creating bean with name 'cardLendRateDAO' defined in file [C:\bitbucket_repos\my-card-app-service\target\classes\com\mydomain\myapp\dao\impl\CardLendRateDAOImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/mydomain/myapp/config/DataSourceConfiguration.class]: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.integrator.UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator could not be instantiated
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:787)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1165)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:815)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at com.mydomain.myapp.MCAApplication.main(MCAApplication.java:18)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cardLendRateService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cardLendRateDAO': Error creating bean with name 'cardLendRateDAO' defined in file [C:\bitbucket_repos\my-card-app-service\target\classes\com\mydomain\myapp\dao\impl\CardLendRateDAOImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/mydomain/myapp/config/DataSourceConfiguration.class]: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.integrator.UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator could not be instantiated
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:787)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cardLendRateDAO' defined in file [C:\bitbucket_repos\my-card-app-service\target\classes\com\mydomain\myapp\dao\impl\CardLendRateDAOImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/mydomain/myapp/config/DataSourceConfiguration.class]: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.integrator.UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator could not be instantiated
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/mydomain/myapp/config/DataSourceConfiguration.class]: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.integrator.UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator could not be instantiated
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:907)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:785)
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.integrator.UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator could not be instantiated
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:586)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:813)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:729)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedServiceLoader$ClassPathAndModulePathAggregatedServiceLoader.collectServiceIfNotDuplicate(AggregatedServiceLoader.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedServiceLoader$ClassPathAndModulePathAggregatedServiceLoader.loadAll(AggregatedServiceLoader.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedServiceLoader$ClassPathAndModulePathAggregatedServiceLoader.getAll(AggregatedServiceLoader.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.create(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:190)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.getMetadataSources(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:446)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:496)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/type/SingleColumnType
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3373)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3578)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:626)
    at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractSingleColumnUserType.<init>(AbstractSingleColumnUserType.java:41)
    at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractParameterizedUserType.<init>(AbstractParameterizedUserType.java:27)
    at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractParameterizedTemporalUserType.<init>(AbstractParameterizedTemporalUserType.java:20)
    at org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime.<init>(PersistentDateTime.java:41)
    at org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.integrator.UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator.<clinit>(UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator.java:60)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:789)
    ... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.type.SingleColumnType
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 92 common frames omitted
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50917', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1

I'm sorry if my description is confusing. English is not my fluent language.
With the use of annotation. I tried replacing @Type with @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.DATE), but I'm not sure this works because I still have problems with the hibernate mapping file.
I looked for a replacement in both Hibernate's user guides and Joda's user guides but couldn't find it. Or maybe I missed something in the documentation.

I thought that Joda time became all but obsolete since the introduction of the new date/time API in Java 8.

So changing from the joda time to another data type is an option. Thanks for the suggestion. I will try with a different date and time data type.
